# Prevent script to stop when there is an issue with a .shp file

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2

I am trying to iterate through all my shapefiles to check if they have a coordinate system assigned or not.

The script works fine and iterates through most of my .shp files, however some files seem to have some issues due to unknown reasons and stop the iteration process. The core part of my script, where the error is located is the following:

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
import os

folder = 'C:\\myfolder'
arcpy.env.workspace = folder
fcs = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()

for shp in fcs:
    print '\t', shp
    dsc = arcpy.Describe(shp) 
    print(arcpy.Exists(shp))
    if dsc.spatialReference is None:
        print('shape not readable: ' + folder)

    else:
        sr = dsc.spatialReference
```

I was able to deal with some problems using the `if dsc.spatialReference is None:` exception.

Currently I am getting the following error which is was not able to find a solution for. I do not necessarily need to resolve that error. I just want to skip that shapefile and continue with my script.

> Runtime error  Traceback (most recent call last):   File "",
>   line 18, in  AttributeError: DescribeData: Method
>   spatialReference does not exist

Any suggestions?

Comment: you can use python's [try](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions)

Comment: In addition to try, you can try using `hasattr`, see the [code example](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-functions/describe-object-properties.htm) here

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a solution using the [try statement](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions). See the code comments for explanation:

```
import arcpy

folder = 'C:\\myfolder'
arcpy.env.workspace = folder
fcs = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()

for shp in fcs:
    print '\t', shp
    dsc = arcpy.Describe(shp)
    print(arcpy.Exists(shp))
    # try statements allow you to test code and keep it from crashing
    try:
        sr = dsc.spatialReference
    # In the case that a line indented under "try:" results in an AttributeError...
    except AttributeError:
        # Do whatever you want. Here, I simply print a notification
        print('The file has no attribute named "spatialReference"')
        # "continue" will stop processing this shp and skip to the next shp in the
        #   for loop
        continue
    if sr is None:
        print('shape not readable: ' + folder)
```

Comment: Thanks. It works like it should. I just wanted to add, that the following error was resolved using `if dsc.spatialReference is None:`, so for others, it might be more robust to keep that line in the script.
--------------
Runtime error 
Traceback (most recent call last):  File "<string>", line 33, in <module> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'name'```

Comment: @ewfun, that line is still there in the form of `if sr is None:`; it simply uses the existing variable to which dsc.spatialReference has already been assigned.